# How can I efficiently generate and compare all possible class schedule combinations using Python?

Tags: python, combinations

I'm trying to build a simple python that finds the optimal schedule based on a provided class schedule dataset.

The idea was for the program to parse the dataset, come up with all the possible combinations, score them, and return the highest resulting schedule.

I came with with this set of criteria for what is optimal (trying to get days off or where you only have online classes) and tried to build code around it:

1. once we choose a block for a course, we must take both classes belonging to that block. For example, if we choose CRPG250 Block A, we would have to take both the Wednesday and the Friday classes because they are both Block A.
2. there cannot be an overlap in times as we cannot take two classes at the same time.
3. we can only choose one course, consisting of two classes (block A, B, C, D, E, or F), for a total of five courses. No more, no less.
4. we must check every combination of 5 courses possible to see which schedule (consisting of 5 courses, they themselves consisting of a block of 2 classes) results in the highest score.
5. Each schedule should receive a score/rating to decide which is the best schedule and a schedule must be comprised of one selection (block A, B, C, D, E, or F) of each course.

- For every day of the week that has only one in-person class, it should receive a score of 1.
- For every day of the week that has only online classes, it should gain by score of 2 for each day that has only online classes.
- For every day of the week that has no classes at all, it should gain a score by 3 for each day without any classes.

6. Once all possible combinations of 5 courses are computed (they themselves consisting of a block of 2 classes (A, B, C, D, E, or F), we should print the schedule(s) with the highest score(s). If there is a clear winner in terms of score print only that one. If there is a tie, print all the schedules that tied for first place.

The following is what I tried, but it hangs when run. I'm not sure if I'm fundamentally wrong or if I'm just creating too many possible combinations. Either way, any help into how I could make something that both worked and did not take a long time to run would be fantastic.

```
from itertools import product


def generate_schedule(courses):
    course_blocks = {}
    for course in courses:
        key = (course["name"], course["block"])
        if key not in course_blocks:
            course_blocks[key] = []
        course_blocks[key].append(course)

    block_combinations = list(product(*course_blocks.values()))

    schedules = []
    max_score = 0

    for combination in block_combinations:
        schedule = list(combination)

        if len(set(course["name"] for course in schedule)) == len(courses):
            if not has_class_time_overlap(schedule):
                result = calculate_schedule_score(schedule)
                score = result["score"]
                if score > max_score:
                    schedules = [result]
                    max_score = score
                elif score == max_score:
                    schedules.append(result)

    return schedules


def has_class_time_overlap(schedule):
    days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]

    for day in days:
        courses_on_day = [course for course in schedule if day in course["days"]]
        if len(courses_on_day) > 1:
            course_times = [course["time"] for course in courses_on_day]
            if len(set(course_times)) < len(courses_on_day):
                return True

    return False


def calculate_schedule_score(schedule):
    days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
    scores = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
    day_schedule = {
        day: [] for day in days
    }  # Initialize an empty schedule for each day

    for day in days:
        class_types = set()
        for course in schedule:
            if day in course["days"]:
                class_types.add(course["type"])
                day_schedule[day].append(course)
        if len(class_types) == 1:
            if "in-person" in class_types:
                scores[1] += 1
            else:
                scores[2] += 1
        elif len(class_types) == 0:
            scores[3] += 1

    total_score = scores[1] * 1 + scores[2] * 2 + scores[3] * 3
    return {"score": total_score, "schedule": day_schedule}


dataset = [
    {
        "name": "CPRG250",
        "type": "online",
        "block": "A",
        "days": ["Friday"],
        "time": "10:00-11:50",
    },
    {
        "name": "CPRG250",
        "type": "in-person",
        "block": "A",
        "days": ["Wednesday"],
        "time": "12:00-14:50",
    },
    # rest of dataset (5 courses, each with 5 blocks in total)
    {
        "name": "CPRG211",
        "type": "in-person",
        "block": "F",
        "days": ["Tuesday"],
        "time": "15:00-17:50",
    },
    {
        "name": "CPRG211",
        "type": "online",
        "block": "F",
        "days": ["Friday"],
        "time": "14:00-15:50",
    },
]

schedules = generate_schedule(dataset)

for schedule in schedules:
    print("Schedule:")
    day_schedule = schedule["schedule"]
    for day, classes in day_schedule.items():
        print(day + ":")
        if not classes:
            print("No classes")
        else:
            for course in classes:
                print(f"{course['name']} - {course['type']} ({course['block']})")
        print()
```